# Update UDF names stored in table to add parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have thousands of UDF names stored in table and executed dynamically where it is required. The problem is I have added one new parameter `unit` to the function `dbo.GetStockPrice(6544,1)` so I need to send one more parameter value for now `1` bue it can be any and the data should be changed to `dbo.GetStockPrice(6544,1,1)` for all the rows where `dbo.GetStockPrice` is exist. So I am seeking for the query to update these all at once.

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(id INT, UDF VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(7774,'dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1)*dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1)'),
(7775,'dbo.GetStockPrice(232,1)'),
(7778,'dbo.GetStockPrice(6456,1)'),
(7780,'dbo.GetStockPrice(34,1)'),
(7784,'dbo.FNACondition(dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0), 0, dbo.GetStockPrice(654,1)+1)'),
(7786,'dbo.GetStockPrice(9876,1)'),
(7906,'dbo.GetStockPrice(5565,1)'),
(7911,'dbo.GetStockPrice(7886,1)'),
(7912,'dbo.GetStockPrice(87,1)'),
(8403,'dbo.PriceValue(479,NULL,NULL)*dbo.GetStockPrice(6544,1)+dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0)')
```

Expected Output:

```
7774    dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1,1)*dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1,1)
7775    dbo.GetStockPrice(232,1,1)
so on......
```

I am still trying with `REPLACE`, `SUBSTRING` but unable to come out with any solution. Getting difficulties with it's different length and position in the row.

Seeking Help !! Thank you in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this approach:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(id INT, UDF VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(7774,'dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1)*dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1)'),
(7775,'dbo.GetStockPrice(232,1)'),
(7778,'dbo.GetStockPrice(6456,1)'),
(7780,'dbo.GetStockPrice(34,1)'),
(7784,'dbo.FNACondition(dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0), 0, dbo.GetStockPrice(654,1)+1)'),
(7786,'dbo.GetStockPrice(9876,1)'),
(7906,'dbo.GetStockPrice(5565,1)'),
(7911,'dbo.GetStockPrice(7886,1)'),
(7912,'dbo.GetStockPrice(87,1)'),
(7913,'dbo.Blah(87,1)'),
(8403,'dbo.PriceValue(479,NULL,NULL)*dbo.GetStockPrice(6544,1)+dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0)');
```

--The query

```
WITH SplitToParts AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,A.parted
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PartNr
          ,B.part.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part
    FROM @table AS t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT t.UDF AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'dbo.GetStockPrice(','</x><x>$$$FoundIt$$$</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(parted)
    CROSS APPLY parted.nodes(N'/x') AS B(part)
    WHERE UDF LIKE '%dbo.GetStockPrice(%'
)
,modified AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN LAG(stp.Part) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY PartNr)='$$$FoundIt$$$' THEN STUFF(stp.Part,CHARINDEX(')',stp.Part),0,',1') ELSE stp.Part END AS Added
    FROM SplitToParts AS stp
)
SELECT t2.*
      ,(
        SELECT REPLACE(m.added,'$$$FoundIt$$$','dbo.GetStockPrice(')
        FROM modified AS m 
        WHERE m.id=t2.id 
        ORDER BY m.PartNr
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @table AS t2
WHERE UDF LIKE '%dbo.GetStockPrice(%';
```

The result

```
7774    dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1,1)*dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,1,1)
7775    dbo.GetStockPrice(232,1,1)
7778    dbo.GetStockPrice(6456,1,1)
7780    dbo.GetStockPrice(34,1,1)
7784    dbo.FNACondition(dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0), 0, dbo.GetStockPrice(654,1,1)+1)
7786    dbo.GetStockPrice(9876,1,1)
7906    dbo.GetStockPrice(5565,1,1)
7911    dbo.GetStockPrice(7886,1,1)
7912    dbo.GetStockPrice(87,1,1)
8403    dbo.PriceValue(479,NULL,NULL)*dbo.GetStockPrice(6544,1,1)+dbo.FNAMargin(1,NULL,0)
```

Some explanation: The string will be cut in parts using your function's name as splitter. Gladfully you tagged this with `[sql-server-2012]` so you can use `LAG()`. This will test the previous element, if it is `$$$FoundIt$$$`. In this case the first closing bracket will get an additional `,1`. The rest is reconcatenation.

Attention: If your call might include a computed value such as

```
dbo.GetStockPrice(1211,(1+2))
or
dbo.GetStockPrice(dbo.SomeOtherFunc(1),1)
```

...the *first closing bracket* is the wrong place to insert the `,1`. But this would get really tricky... You'd have to run through it, char by char, and count the opening brackets to find the related closing one.

Comment: Unfortunately getting this error `"XML parsing: line 1, character 40, illegal qualified name character"` while trying to my real table. FYI there many other rows also that doesn't include this function to be replaced. Is this the problem ?

Comment: @Susang, hang on a minute. I did not expected illegal XML characters here. place an update soon...

Comment: @Susang, you can try it again.

Comment: @Susang One hint: You should filter this to the lines including this UDF by adding `WHERE UDF LIKE '%dbo.GetStockPrice(%'`. This must be done in the first cte **and** in the final `SELECT`